# Groovy call operator throws MissingMethodException when used on a class field

Tags: groovy

I am trying to use call operator `()` overloading, but it does not work on class fields. What's wrong?

```
class Foo {
    void call(int x){
        println("x="+x)
    }
}

class MyCallable {
    Foo foo = new Foo()
}

Foo foo = new Foo() 
foo(5)  //works

MyCallable mc = new MyCallable()
mc.foo(2) //not works
```

But program terminated with exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
signature of method: mpctests.MyCallable.foo() is applicable for
argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [2]
```

Comment: How is this even compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `MissingMethodException` when you call `mc.foo(5)`, because Groovy's invoke object method mechanism gets triggered. There is one thing worth explaining to get a better understanding about this situation. Your `MyCallable` class:

```
class MyCallable {
    Foo foo = new Foo()
}
```

gets compiled to something like this:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class MyCallable implements GroovyObject {
    private Foo foo;

    public MyCallable() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        Object var2 = var1[0].callConstructor(Foo.class);
        this.foo = (Foo)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var2, Foo.class);
        MetaClass var3 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var3;
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo var1) {
        this.foo = var1;
    }
}
```

Groovy also compiles every field access like `mc.foo` to a getter method call `mc.getFoo()`. So when you call `mc.foo(5)` it is clear for Groovy runtime that you expect to call a `foo(5)` method on `mc` object. And this method does not exist and `MissingMethodException` gets thrown.

However, it works if you create object `def foo = new Foo()` and then you call `foo(5)`, because `foo` is an object and `foo(5)` is a strict instruction to invoke `call(5)` method on `foo` object (`foo(5)` is a shorthand version of `foo.call(5)`). The same situation would take place if you call `mc()` - Groovy would try to invoke `mc.call()` method. But when you say `mc.foo(5)` it's clear that you are trying to invoke `foo(5)` method.

---

If you want to use call operator on `mc.foo` field there are two options:

#### 1. Use direct field access operator `@`

```
mc.@foo(5)
```

In this case you refer directly to `foo` field and you can use shorthand call operator.

#### 2. Use `with {}` method

```
mc.with {
    foo(5)
}
```

In this case it is also a straightforward for Groovy runtime that you are accessing `foo` field and you can use call operator on it.

#### Alternatives

Using getter method:

```
mc.getFoo()(5)
```

Using method `call()` directly:

```
mc.foo.call(5) // equivalent of mc.getFoo().call(5)
```

Comment: Another way: `(mc.foo)()`